# How to enter text into a text field nested in an iFrame?

Tags: automated-testing, cucumber, ruby

I am using Ruby with Cucumber and attempting to build up a suite of automated tests against a dynamics 2013 system. We have a cart that is a nested into an iFrame and we are attempting to enter a product into a text field.

The code that we have is :

```
@browser.switch.frame(id: 'navLink{bd27b00e-3d5e-b7b5-0ddb-864216077292}AreaFrame')
@browser.input(id: 'addQuickProductTextBox').set("MM-000001-NF Nurse Full")
```

But using this code I get the message:

> Watir::Exception::UnknownFrameException: unable to locate iframe using
>   {:id=>"navLink{bd27b00e-3d5e-b7b5-0ddb-864216077292}AreaFrame",
>   :tag_name=>"iframe"}

The HTML is in attached snap:

[image: Top Level IFrames]
[image: Table Details]
[image: Data Field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the image you attached, it seems that you are using the wrong id for iframe.
Its id value should be "contentIFrame1".

In Watir you can do something like:

```
@browser.iframe(id: 'contentIFrame1').iframe(id:'navLink{bd27b00e-3d5e-b7b5-0ddb-864216077292}AreaFrame').text_field(id: 'addQuickProductTextBox').set("MM-000001-NF Nurse Full")
```

Comment: Hi Roman. Thank you for the suggestion, however trying that returns the following error - Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::TextField: located: false; {:id=>"contentIFrame1", :tag_name=>"iframe"} --> {:id=>"addQuickProductTextBox", :tag_name=>"input"}> to be located

Comment: oh, sorry, I didn't see the second iframe there.
Check if this work so:

`@browser.iframe(id: 'contentIFrame1').iframe(id:"'navLink{bd27b00e-3d5e-b7b5-0ddb-864216077292}AreaFrame'").text_field(id: 'addQuickProductTextBox').set("MM-000001-NF Nurse Full")`

If it works, I'll update the first answer.
For more info about frames [iframe](http://watir.com/guides/frames/)

Comment: Hi Roman. Thank you that helped the code that worked in the end is - @browser.iframe(id: 'contentIFrame1').iframe(id:'navLink{bd27b00e-3d5e-b7b5-0ddb-864216077292}AreaFrame').text_field(id: 'addQuickProductTextBox').set("MM-000001-NF Nurse Full")